# Saving NSArray in SQLite and retrieving it

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, nsarray, nsdata

In my iPHone app I am saving an NSArray in sqlite like this.

```
-(void)saveData

 NSData *dataFromArray = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:MyArray];



   sqlite3_stmt    *statement;
   const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];

   if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &contactDB) == SQLITE_OK)
   {
      NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"INSERT INTO ARRAY(PROFILE) VALUES (\"%@\")",dataFromArray];


    const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];
    sqlite3_prepare_v2(contactDB, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);
    if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
    {
        NSLog(@"Saved Succesfully");

       }
     else {
        // NSAssert1(0, @"Error while inserting data. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(contactDB));
        NSLog(@"Not saved %d",sqlite3_finalize(statement));
       }
      sqlite3_finalize(statement);
      sqlite3_close(contactDB);
    }

  }
```

Data is saved successfully.

Now I tried to fetch the saved data like this-

```
 -(void)fetchData{

  const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
  sqlite3_stmt    *statement;

  if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &contactDB) == SQLITE_OK)
  {
    NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"SELECT * FROM ARRAY"];
    const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(contactDB, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        while(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            NSString *MYstring = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];


             NSData* data = [MYstring dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

            NSLog(@"data---%@",data);


           NSArray *myArrayFromDB = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];



           }
          sqlite3_finalize(statement);
         }
          sqlite3_close(contactDB);
        }

     }
```

I am getting print value for "MYstring" like this

```
<62706c69 73743030 d4000100 02000300 04000500 0806cb06 cc542474 6f705824 6f626a65 63747358 24766572 73696f6e 59246172 63686976 6572d100 06000754 726f6f74 8001af11 022a0009 000a0017 00180019 001a0080 00810082 00830084 00850086 00870088 0089008a 008b008c 008d008e 008f0090 00910092 00930094 00950096 00970098 0099009a 009b009c 009d009e 009f00a0 00a100a2 00a300a4 00a500a6 00a700a8 00a900aa 00ab00ac 00ad00ae 00af00b0 00b100b5 00bd00c0 00c300c6 00c900cc 00cf00d2 00d500d8 00db00de 00e100e4 00e700ea 00ed00f0 00fd0105 0108010b 010e0111 01140117 011a011d 01200122 0127012a 012d0130 01330136 0139013c 013f0142 01450148 014b014e 01510154 0159015e 01610164 0169016f 018101a1 01a201a3 01a401a5 01a601a7 01a801a9 01aa01ab 01ac01ad 01ae01af 01b201b5 01b801bb 01be01c1 01c401c7 01ca01cd 01d001d3 01d601d9 01f901fa 01fb01fc>
```

But when I try to create NSArray from data using NSKeyedUnarchiver - the app got crashed showing this error

```
   -[__NSCFData objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Where I am making the mistake ?
Please help me to retrieve the saved array, Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to convert the data back into some other object type. `-[__NSCFData objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance` tells you that you've used the `objectForKey` method on an NSData object... suggesting you really need it as an NSDictionary perhaps.

Comment: Do `NSLog("%@", dataFromArray);` and count the unescaped quotes.

Comment: Where did the above "unrecognized selector" exception come from??  We don't see you trying to index anything in your listing.  Are you indexing `myArrayFromDB` or are you indexing `data`?

Comment: @HotLicks first I am converting my NSArray to NSData *dataFromArray = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:MyArray]; then saving in DB.  While retrieving I cannot convert this data back to Array

Comment: I see that, but that's not what I asked.  You do NSKeyedArchiver unarchive... but then report an error indexing an NSData.  You'd have us believe that unarchive returned an NSData???

Comment: (And if you're saving/restoring NSData you should save/restore a *blob*.)

Comment: (You might be interested to use sqlite3 from the command line to examine your DB.  What you will find in the table is something like "<f7323467 8ed27689 ...".)

Comment: @HotLicks You are talking about some other things i believe. mah may be right.

Comment: You're never going to create anything from that data, since it was corrupted before you inserted it.  That can be seen from the value you printed as myString -- it's a `description` dump of an NSData object.  But you would not get `[__NSCFData objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector` from unarchiveObjectWithData, so there are other strange things going on as well.

Comment: Basically, you don't understand what you're doing.  You're effectively creating a table with only one entry, and not doing that very well.  If you want the table with only one entry the column needs to be a *blob*, though it would probably make more sense to simply store the NSData object as a file.  If you want to use the DB you should really store one element of the array in each row of the DB table, vs all in one row.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use NSData? Once the string received, write below line

```
NSArray *myArrayFromDB = [MYstring componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

Try this if it is working. Let me know if not and I find another solution

Comment: This can be an easiest way if the array values are not containing a comma within their values.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSData *dataFromArray = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:myArray];
```

This creates an XML representation of myArray and places it in dataFromArray.  Something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist SYSTEM "file://localhost/System/Library/DTDs/PropertyList.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <string>It is a tale told by an idiot,</string>
    <string>Full of sound and fury, signifying nothing.</string>
</array>
</plist>
```

The XML is converted to UTF8 format and stored in the NSData object.

When you do:

```
NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"INSERT INTO ARRAY(PROFILE) VALUES (\"%@\")",dataFromArray];
```

the `stringWithFormat` operation interprets the format string.  When it sees `%@`, it thinks "I must take the next object reference from the parameter list, apply the `description` method to it, and place that into the string."

The `description` method of NSData takes the `<?xml version...` data and converts it into displayable hex (since `description` is intended to be used purely for debugging, never "real" code).  The displayable hex is formatted in groups of 8 characters, separated by blanks and enclosed in "<>" characters.  By now the data is hopelessly garbled, and you haven't even inserted it into the DB yet.